# Objective-C: EXC_BAD_ACCESS and doesn't respond

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Here's the header file:

```
@interface calc : NSObject {
    IBOutlet NSTextField *tf1;
    IBOutlet NSTextField *tf2;
    IBOutlet NSTextField *ansr;
    int s;
}

- (IBAction)add:(id)sender;

@end
```

And here's the implementation file:

```
@implementation calc

- (IBAction)add:(id)sender
{
    s = [tf1 intValue] + [tf2 intValue];
    [ansr setStringValue:(@"%@", s)];



}
- (void) dealloc {
    [tf1 release];
    tf1 = nil;
    [tf2 release];
    tf2 = nil;
    [ansr release];
    ansr = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Comment: Try running it under the debugger - execution will stop at the line where the bad memory access occurs and this should then tell you what you've done wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

s is an int, not an object.

Try this instead :

```
- (IBAction)add:(id)sender
{
    s = [tf1 intValue] + [tf2 intValue];
    [ansr setIntValue:s];
```

Comment: This is a part of the answer but the same problem will appear. `setStringValue:` doesn't accept formatting.

Comment: @gcamp You're right. You would have to set it using `-[NSString stringWithFormat:]`.

Comment: @gcamp and @deanWorbourne, thanks for answering my question both methods work.  Sorry for such a newbie question.

Answer (score 3):

`setStringValue:` doesn't accept more than one argument like `printf` and `stringWithFormat:` does.

You should do something like

```
s = [tf1 intValue] + [tf2 intValue];
NSString* result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", s];
[ansr setStringValue:result];
```